# How to refer to the phenomenon of people only absorbing evidence which confirms their beliefs?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, terminology, bias

I knew a psychologist who was calling it *self-referentiality*.

People are always trying to see only the *sentence* which confirm their ***beliefs***.

What's the correct name for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual act of "Trying to see only the sentence which confirms his beliefs" would generally be called [confirmation bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias).